# php find word in string by char(letter) position

Tags: php, string, substring, words

Is there any way to find the word in a string by having one of the letter's position in the string. I mean if there is any easy way of doing it.

I have a string for example with 250 chars and 70 words. I would need to limit the string in my div so I need to get the whole string with complete words before char 100.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Provide an example string and the desired output? For example, do you mean with string `this is a test` and position `11` it will return `test`?

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Have you tried the strrchr(string,char) function of php

Comment: I have a string by for example 250 chars and 70 words. I would need to limit the string in my div so I need to get the whole string words before char 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the simplest answer:

```
substr($text, 0, strrpos(substr($text, 0, 100), " " ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Is't simply. You car use this function.

```
$string = "Hello world I use PHP";
$position = 7;

function getWordFromStringInPosition ($string, $position)
{
    if (strlen($string) == 0) throw new Exception("String is empty.");
    if ($position > strlen($string) || $position < 0) throw new Exception("The position is outside of the text");
    $words = explode(" ", $string);

    $count = 0;

    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        if ($position > $count && $position < $count + strlen($word) + 1)
        {
            return $word;
        }
        else
        {
            $count += strlen($word) + 1;
        }
    }
}

echo getWordFromStringInPosition ($string, $position); // world
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This function is also very useful.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a string by for example 250 chars and 70 words. I would need to
>   limit the string in my div so I need to get the whole string words
>   before char 100.

Here's a little something I was able to throw together:

```
function getPartialString($string, $max)
{

  $words = explode(' ', $string);

  $i = 0;

  $new_string = array();

  foreach ($words as $k => $word)
  {

    $length = strlen($word);

    if ($max < $length + $i + $k)
    {
      break;
    }

    $new_string[] = $word;

    $i += $length;

  }

  return implode(' ', $new_string);

}

echo getPartialString('this is a test', 6); // this

echo getPartialString('this is a test', 7); // this is
```

Comment: Thanks, although it is not as simple as I thought but it is getting what I need.